# Basic help to execute html file containing php .htaccess file config

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Goal:
Executing HTML files that contain PHP commands(like [this](http://caravans4hire.butlinsminehead.co.uk/calltransfer.html) which is just a basic script to demo.  The only output I get is Welcome to my home 1page, the hello world from the PHP is not running)

If I can get this to run I have PHP to extract data from a database.

Problem:
Despite changing the `.htaccess` file located at the root domain of `butlinsminehead.co.uk` nothing that I add has any effect.  I have many options

```
including AddHandler php-fastcgi `.php` `.php5` `.php72`
AddType text/html `.php .php5 .php72`
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php5 index.php72
```

I believe I am running php7 although this is the output:

```
System  Linux zebedee3.namesco.net 2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 9 17:27:49 UTC 2018 x86_64
Build Date  Sep 20 2016 12:10:20
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
```

Does anyone know what the .htaccess file should contain, please?

The HTML is running in a subdomain for `butlinsminehead.co.uk`

Comment: AddHandler php70-script .php .php5 .html .htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper type, which is `application/x-httpd-php` instead of `text/html`.

You can read the `AddType` directive as *X type is handled by Y files` so:

`AddType text/html .php .php5 .php72`

Would be *Html type is handled by PHP files* and what you want is *PHP type is handled by HTML files*:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .php72`

If it doesn't work you try with `application/x-httpd-php5`.